# Taxonomy templates

Tags: taxonomy-terms, theming

I have a view that lists all the terms in my taxonomy. When you click the link (url structure is ([tax_name]/[tax_term]) it takes you through to a page that has the description of the term  and then the outputed content with the content types template, one after the other. Now I want to edit this template but I can't figure it out. I found taxonomy-term.tpl.php within the taxonomy module. But when I put this into my templates folder nothing I do seems to effect it. I have also tried taxonomy-term--[tax_name].tpl but no luck. From what I can see this is all I should have to do? I have of course cleared the cache. What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

Views 3.0 comes with a view that replaces the normal taxonomy page. This view is disabled by default but you may have enabled it. Make sure the view *Taxonomy term* is not enabled; then, you can use your custom template to override the default template.

If this doesn't work, you can try using this code.

```
function template_preprocess_page(&$variables) {
  if (arg(0) == 'taxonomy') {
    $variables['theme_hook_suggestions'][] = 'page__taxonomy';
  }
}
```

You should now be able to create the page--taxonomy.tpl.php file in your theme folder.

Of course you can also enable the *Taxonomy term* view and override that template (*Edit view*, under *Advanced* click *Theme: information*).

Comment: ah ok, so mean the list of all my views I see 'taxonomy term' but this is not enabled, or do you mean within my term view?

Comment: I meant the one in your list of views. What happens when you modify the default template? Do you see the changes?

Comment: it doesn't seem to pick any of them up, even when I edit the core file nothing happens. So it's not picking the file up at all I don't think

Comment: True, it seems as if the default theming is not applied here. Can you do a dpm or print_r in a hook_preprocess_page somewhere and check what values there are in $variables['theme_hook_suggestions'] if you visit your taxonomy page?

Comment: Have tried print_r and var_dump and get nothing and null respectively

Comment: So just to be clear I am looking to control the template for tax/term so lets say i create a taxonomy called 'star trek' and I then created a term called 'Klingon' and tagged a bunch of content types lets call them 'people' with this term, it's the page full of people who are Klingon I want to modify

Comment: I updated my answer, please let me know if it helps you.

Comment: Hey cool thanks, its actually doing something now! But I'm not able to figure what I'd call to get the items now. I just want to loop around the terms ideally, can't figure out anything that works for that.

Comment: Which method do you use?

Comment: I am trying to var_dump $node and $content but it returns null

Comment: Are you using template_preprocess_page? If so, does $variables contains the content?

Comment: oh sorry yeah, preprocess, ok cool yeah that's outputted a lot of stuff, $variables that is, not sure where to start with all of that!

Comment: Every element key in the root of the `$variables` array will be available in the template file as an actual variable. So let's say you have `$variables['content']`, you should be able to print it in your template simply with `$content`. Also, a debugging tip: if you want to know which variables you have in your template, print_r this php function: [get_defined_vars()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.get-defined-vars.php)

Comment: ah ok cool thanks, if i do variables['content'] i get null

Comment: Isn't there anything you can use in `$variables`? Because you've created your own template, you're in full control what happens with the data. This means you need to format the data to your liking in the preprocess function and only then display it in your template.

Comment: Yeah, it's all there but it's how I'd get the term id and then pass this in to get the correct one i'm struggling with

Comment: Maybe [this](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21taxonomy%21taxonomy.pages.inc/function/taxonomy_term_page/7) helps, it's the default code used by taxonomy for generating the term page. All you need there is the `$term` object which probably can be found somewhere in `$variables`.

Answer (score 0):

In this [taxonomy_template](https://www.drupal.org/node/1089656) describe how customize template of taxonomy term in drupal

**`taxonomy-term--[vocabulary-machine-name|tid].tpl.php`**

base template: `taxonomy-term.tpl.php`

Theme hook suggestions are made based on these factors, listed from the most specific template to the least. Drupal will use the most specific template it finds:

1. taxonomy-term--tid.tpl.php
2. taxonomy-term--vocabulary-machine-name.tpl.php
3. taxonomy-term.tpl.php

Note that underscores in a vocabulary's machine name are replaced by hyphens.